# Strange type error in Haskell let-expression -- what's the issue?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, let

I came across a frustrating *something* in Haskell today.

Here's what happened:

1. I wrote a function in ghci and gave it a type signature
2. ghci complained about the type
3. I removed the type signature
4. ghci accepted the function
5. I checked the inferred type
6. the inferred type was exactly the same as the type I tried to give it
7. I was very distressed
8. I discovered that I could reproduce the problem in any let-expression
9. Gnashing of teeth; decided to consult with the experts at SO

---

**Attempt to define the function with a type signature:**

```
Prelude Control.Monad> let myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x} :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b

<interactive>:1:20:
    Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected
      Quantified type variable `b' is mentioned in the environment:
        m :: (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b (bound at <interactive>:1:16)
        f :: (m b -> m b) -> Bool (bound at <interactive>:1:14)
      Quantified type variable `m' is mentioned in the environment:
        m :: (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b (bound at <interactive>:1:16)
        f :: (m b -> m b) -> Bool (bound at <interactive>:1:14)
    In the expression:
          do { x <- m;
               guard (f x);
               return x } ::
            (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
    In the definition of `myFilterM':
        myFilterM f m
                    = do { x <- m;
                           guard (f x);
                           return x } ::
                        (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
```

**Defined the function without a type signature, checked the inferred type:**

```
Prelude Control.Monad> let myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x}
Prelude Control.Monad> :t myFilterM 
myFilterM :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
```

**Used the function for great good -- it worked properly:**

```
Prelude Control.Monad> myFilterM (>3) (Just 4)
Just 4
Prelude Control.Monad> myFilterM (>3) (Just 3)
Nothing
```

---

*My best guess as to what is going on:*
type annotations somehow don't work well with let-expressions, when there's a do-block.

*For bonus points:*
is there a function in the standard Haskell distribution that does this?  I was surprised that `filterM` does something very different.

Comment: The type annotation applies to the RHS of the definition, not to `myFilterM`, so you should be saying `:: (MonadPlus m) => m b`. This is why the types for `m` and `f` in your error message are so strange. But I still get the "Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected" error message (albeit with more sensible types) and I don't know what causes that.

Comment: @dave4420 Do you also use GHC 6.*? They coded a new type-inference engine in GHC 7; maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @FUZxxl That was with GHC 6.12.1. I've just tried it with GHC 7.0.3 and I get two error messages instead of one, neither of them mentioning polymorphism. It might be GHC 7 refusing to infer the types of `myFilterM`'s arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the precedence of the type operator (`::`).  You're trying to describe the type of `myFilterM` but what you're actually doing is this:

```
ghci> let myFilterM f m = (\
        do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x} \
        :: \
        (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b)\
      )
```

(backslashes inserted for readability only, not legit ghci syntax)

Do you see the issue?  I get the same problem for something simple like

```
ghci> let f x = x + 1 :: (Int -> Int)
<interactive>:1:15:
    No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Int -> Int))
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `1'
    In the expression: x + 1 :: Int -> Int
    In an equation for `f': f x = x + 1 :: Int -> Int
```

The solution is to attach the type signature to the proper element:

```
ghci> let f :: Int -> Int ; f x = x + 1
ghci> let myFilterM :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b; myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x}
```

And for bonus points, you want [`mfilter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3amfilter) ([hoogle is your friend](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28MonadPlus%20m%29%20%3D%3E%20%28b%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20m%20b%20-%3E%20m%20b)).

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe I'd never run in to this before while using ghci.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely just an issue of type annotation syntax and binding precendence. If you write your example as,

```
let myFilterM :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b; myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x}
```

then GHCi will give you a high-five and send you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of compiler you use, but on my platform (GHC 7.0.3) I get a simple type mismatch:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m +Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> let myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x} :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b

<interactive>:1:30:
    Could not deduce (t1 ~ ((b1 -> Bool) -> m1 b1 -> m1 b1))
    from the context (MonadPlus m)
      bound by the inferred type of
               myFilterM :: MonadPlus m => t -> t1 -> (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
      at <interactive>:1:5-100
    or from (MonadPlus m1)
      bound by an expression type signature:
                 MonadPlus m1 => (b1 -> Bool) -> m1 b1 -> m1 b1
      at <interactive>:1:21-100
      `t1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of
           myFilterM :: MonadPlus m => t -> t1 -> (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
           at <interactive>:1:5
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: x <- m
    In the expression:
        do { x <- m;
             guard (f x);
             return x } ::
          MonadPlus m => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
    In an equation for `myFilterM':
        myFilterM f m
          = do { x <- m;
                 guard (f x);
                 return x } ::
              MonadPlus m => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b

<interactive>:1:40:
    Could not deduce (t ~ ((m1 b1 -> m1 b1) -> Bool))
    from the context (MonadPlus m)
      bound by the inferred type of
               myFilterM :: MonadPlus m => t -> t1 -> (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
      at <interactive>:1:5-100
    or from (MonadPlus m1)
      bound by an expression type signature:
                 MonadPlus m1 => (b1 -> Bool) -> m1 b1 -> m1 b1
      at <interactive>:1:21-100
      `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the inferred type of
          myFilterM :: MonadPlus m => t -> t1 -> (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
          at <interactive>:1:5
    The function `f' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `t' has none
    In the first argument of `guard', namely `(f x)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: guard (f x)
Prelude Control.Monad>
```

I guess the problem lies in the fact, that the `::` does not reaches the argument. This small variation (note the separate type declaration)

```
let myFilterM f m = do {x <- m; guard (f x); return x}; myFilterM :: (MonadPlus m) => (b -> Bool) -> m b -> m b
```

runs without problems. It may be related to the new type-checker in GHC 7.